# Wordpress redirect after page slug change

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I stuck on a small problem. My site has an active page with slug xyz. I want to replace them by an updated page.
So I rename:
xyz -> xyz_old
xyz_new -> xyz

But when I call www.targetsite.com/xyz wordpress performs an 301 redirect to xyz_old

I removed also the content of wp_old_slug_redirect() in query.php to test it, but still the same behavior. Checked also the htaccess file's, no redirections. Checked mysql tables as well, nothing with this slug in postmeta data....

Any idea?

Thanks!

Regards,
Waldemar

Answer (score 1):

Ok... After a lot of effort, I found the reason: Yoast Plugin :-(

The Plugin creates the redirection mapping automatically after rename of the page.